# How to list all available reviews for coder?

Tags: 7, drush

I am using `drush` with Coder (7.x-2.x) and I would like to know what are available options for reviews:

```
$ drush help coder
...
--reviews Run the specified review(s), "all" runs all reviews, also accepts a comma separated list (no spaces).
```

Where I can find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list will depend on which modules you have that implemented [`hook_reviews()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!coder!coder_review!coder_review.api.php/function/hook_reviews/7); hook implementations return a keyed array that has the name of the review. These items are combined with a default list that come from the coder_review module.

The default list come from that [dir](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/coder/tree/coder_review/includes?h=7.x-2.x) is: `upgrade47`,   `upgrade5x`, `upgrade6x`, `upgrade7x`, `upgrade8x`, `comment`, `druplart`, `i18n`, `i18n_po`, `production`, `security`, `sniffer`, `sql`, `style`

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found the following `drush` command as workaround:

```
drush ev 'require_once dirname((new ReflectionFunction("drush_coder_review"))->getFileName()) . "/coder_review.common.inc"; print_r(array_keys(coder_review_reviews()));'
```

or:

```
drush ev 'require_once str_replace("drush.inc", "common.inc", (new ReflectionFunction("drush_coder_review"))->getFileName()); print_r(array_keys(coder_review_reviews()));'
```

<sup>Note: I'm not using `module_load_include()` in above examples, as Coder module could be downloaded outside of Drupal directory.</sup>

I've also raised [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2605842) for Coder to achieve that in more convenient way.